# Reading a XML file using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read a complex XML file using LinQ.

The XML file has a lot of levels, how can get all value in one ILIST<> . there are more tags in items.enter code here

The XML has the following syntax:

```
<root>
  <items>
    <index_0>
      <product_id>19</product_id>
      <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
      <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
      <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
      <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
      <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
      <menu_value>7.0</menu_value>
    </index_0>
    <index_1>
      <product_id>20</product_id>
      <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
      <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
      <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
      <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
      <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
      <menu_value>10.0</menu_value>
    </index_1>
    <index_2>
      <product_id>21</product_id>
      <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
      <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
      <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
      <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
      <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
      <menu_value>14.0</menu_value>
    </index_2>
  </items>
  <d1>2011-09-30 13:00:00</d1>
  <d2>2013-05-24 13:00:00</d2>
  <num_items>4</num_items>
  <total_retail>2.05</total_retail>
  <total_sale>2.05</total_sale>
  <total_cost>1.64</total_cost>
  <total_discount_amount>0.41</total_discount_amount>
  <balance>1.64</balance>
</root>
```

I have tried this approach :

```
var vrresult = from a in xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/root/items/*")
                           select new
                           {                                                              
                               when = a.Element("when").Value,
                               agent_name = a.Element("agent_name").Value,
                               ani = a.Element("ani").Value,
                              product_description = a.Element("product_description").Value,
                               sale = a.Element("sale").Value,
                               cost = a.Element("cost").Value
                           };
```

**How i can get "total cost" & "balance" value?**

```
  <total_sale>2.05</total_sale>
  <total_cost>1.64</total_cost>
  <total_discount_amount>0.41</total_discount_amount>
  <balance>1.64</balance>
```

Any Suggestions Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code,

> var costNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/total_cost")

and similarly,

```
var balanceNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/balance")
```

from these two XmlElements, you can easily extract the values.

Since you had an `xPath` already, I have suggested this approcah.